# Can not bind click event in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show a simple example

```js
var app =angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.directive('callapi', function($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000,
        compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
             alert('clicked');
            });
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {},
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    $compile(iElement)(scope);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
 $scope.simpleList = [1,2,3]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app=myApp>
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <table>
      <button callapi='api/user'>outerNgRepeat</button>
      <tr ng-repeat='r in simpleList'>
        <td>r</td>
        <td>r</td>
        <td><button callapi='api/user'>innerNgRepeat</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

but  there is a question
[image]

I had try to bind click event on an element  in a directive,but it does not work when it is in ng-repeat.
How to bind click on an element in ng-repeat?

Comment: Screenshots of code are not appropriate for asking a question

Comment: Please provide the code instead of screenshot

Comment: Sorry about this,but i got another question in the jsfiddle code....

Answer (score 1):

You don't wanna bind your events in the `compile` phase for those that are within in an `ng-repeat` block.
Actually, I think you don't have anything to do in the `compile` phase for that particular directive: I reckon you should simply use the `link` callback.

Also, the error you get:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

... refers to your (recursive) using of `$compile`, in the `post`-link hook on your directive.

Check out my code snippet below, updated from yours:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('callapi', function($compile, $rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    terminal: true,
    priority: 1000,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked: ' + scope.r);
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.simpleList = [1, 2, 3];
});
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}  

tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th, td {
    padding: 2px 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app=myApp>
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <table>
      <button callapi='api/user'>outerNgRepeat</button>
      <tr ng-repeat='r in simpleList'>
        <td>r</td>
        <td>r</td>
        <td>
          <button callapi='api/user'>innerNgRepeat</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But why it is not work in compile(because  i need to judje the user's auth befor the button appear depend on the callapi='url' ).